# Error Code : 15005 Processor Decline in Paypal

Tags: magento-1, paypal

I have created a dummy country in magento for some requirement. I have created a store and assigned that dummy country as default country for that store, by using configuration

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> General(Countries Options) -> Default Country = Dummy Country.
```

I am using PayPal Payments Pro to process payments.
Now when I am trying to place an order from this particular store, it gives me error:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. This transaction cannot be processed. (# 15005: Processor Decline)

To resolve this, I overridden the core file :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php
```

in the function `_applyCountryWorkarounds`

```
if (isset($request['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE']) && $request['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'] == 'YC') {
    $request['SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE'] = 'AF';
}
```

Here, `YC` is the code of the dummy country, I change it to `AF`.

But still I face the error #15005. Can anyone suggest the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that means that the bank declined the CC and not PayPal. 
See [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/servicemanagement_help/vterror.htm) and search for #15005

And this usually happens because of an AVS miss match as mentioned [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1425&actp=LIST).

Try another card or another billing address and it should be fine.